# Открытие HTTP сервера apache2 в глобальную сеть

Tags: linux, apache, debian, веб-сервер, apache2

Поставил перед собой цель: создать и настроить какой-никакой веб сервер. С начала использовал слишком сложный гайд с каким то докером, но не справился (в принципе, и не удивительно, я совсем новичок в linux). Танцевал над этим недели две. Потом понял, что нужно начать с чего-то полегче и наконец нашел легкий (для меня) способ с помощью Apache2 (Справился за один вечер).

Установил систему. Скачал нужные утилиты (ufw, apache2 и тд). Из попытки создания с помощью докера уже вынес настройку на роутере переадресации портов на порты сервера - 80:80, 443:443, 3000:3000. Приобрел бесплатный домен, на сайте домена присвоил домену IP роутера (сначала почему то присваивал внешний IP сервера). По гайду настроил все конфиги в Apache2, заменил стандартный файл html и .conf на свои. Все работает как надо. Из браузера в локальной сети доступ к моему сайту имеется как по внутреннему IP сервера, так и по внешнему IP роутера и по домену.

Уж думал, что НАКОНЕЦ ТАКИ хоть какой-то результат, теперь можно показать и своим друзьям, похвастаться, а нет.

Суть проблемы: из сети подключенной не к моему роутеру доступ к сайту не осуществляется.

Система:

---Debian 11

Роутер:

TP-Link с прошивкой DD-WRT, дядя отдал, а он шаманить любит :)

Ко всему прочему открыт для критики и советов по поводу изучения создания веб-серверов.

Comment: зайди на роутер и посмотри ip адрес. если начинается с 10 , 100 , 192, 172 - то не будет работать  с этим интернетом

Comment: @eri Внешний IP роутера?? Он - да, начинается с 100. И что, правда не будет и никак не решить эту проблему что ли? А в чем тогда собственно проблема?..

Comment: доп.услуга - статический IP адрес

Comment: так ладно, я уже и сам допер до причины проблемы. Теперь вопрос: с подключением белого IP все будет исправно работать? (хотя бы скорее всего?)

Comment: не гарантируем, все зависит от прямоты рук мастера :) роутер возможно нужно будет настраивать, 80 порт наружу выставлять или какой другой.

Comment: Ладно, понял, спасибо. Придется тратить на 200 студенческих кровных больше :с

Comment: псс... если тут остался еще кто из профи, можете подсказать как для html импортировать в мой линукс изображения всякие более-менее просто, а то как то непонятен мне этот процесс через командную строку

Comment: Настроить SSH на Linux и воспользоваться любым SFTP клиентом.

Comment: Ссылка на всякий случай https://losst.pro/nastrojka-ssh-v-debian Можно сперва проверить не установлен ли уже ssh и если нет, то установить, дальше можно подключаться удаленно. Там же советы по безопасности, если уж вы решили открывать доступ наружу.

Comment: @hatehatehate вместо покупки статического айпи рассмотри покупку виртуалки. от 100 рублей, нормальная 230р.

Comment: @eri Да я уже купил статику и поставил, правда из-за "качества" провайдера пришлось посидеть пару дней без интернета, но не суть. Я, собственно, сервер ставлю для изучения чего-то нового, хочется сначала пощупать как оно работает на деле, так скажем начать с самых низов. Может я и не прав, поэтому открыт для советов. Кстати, сервер поднялся и все работает (хоть и с обычной html-кой на борту).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Серый IP-адрес не позволит контактировать глобальной сети с вашим сервером, поэтому придется тратиться и подключать у провайдера дополнительную услугу в виде белого IP.